# rails 4 bootstrap 3 ajax modal

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ajax, twitter-bootstrap

I'm busy learning Rails 4 and I would like to display a bootstrap popup modal when a user clicks on a link, when the modal opens it needs to show the information relating to that particular record. 
Heres what I have done so far, which just doesn't show the actual modal popup BUT does pass the correct parameters.

index.html.erb page has:

```
<%= link_to "view", work_path(w), remote: true, :"data-toggle" => 'modal', :"data-target" => '#myModal' %>

<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true"></div>
```

I also have a works/_modal.html.erb:

```
<div class="modal-dialog">
<div class="modal-content">
  <div class="modal-header">
   <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;          </button>
    <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel"></h4>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-body">
  <%= @work.name %>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-footer">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```

also a works controller:

```
    def show
    @work = Work.find(params[:id])
    if request.xhr?
    respond_to do |format|
        format.html {render :partial => 'modal'}
        format.json {head :ok}
    end
end
end
```

and finally a works/show.js.erb:

```
$("#myModal").html("<%= escape_javascript(render 'modal') %>");
```

I hope i'm missing something easy here. in the console I can see the following message so i know it is returning the correct information, but unfortunately it is not showing the modal.:

```
Started GET "/works/8" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-03-03 09:31:12 +0000
Processing by WorksController#show as JS
Parameters: {"id"=>"8"}
Work Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  "works".* FROM "works"  WHERE "works"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", 8]]
Rendered works/_modal.html.erb (4.9ms)
Completed 200 OK in 8ms (Views: 6.3ms | ActiveRecord: 0.2ms)
```

Any help on this is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you added a div having id "myModal"?

Comment: yes, in the index.html.erb there is a div with id="myModal"

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Have a try with another way. In this way, we are going to show the modal popup using explicit javascript command.

In index.html.erb

```
<%= link_to "view", work_path(w), remote: true, class: 'static-popup-link'%>

<div class="modal hide fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" data-backdrop="static" data-keyboard="false">Loading...</div>
```

In application.js

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  var clickOnPopupLink = function(){
    $('body').on('click', '.static-popup-link', function(){
      $('#myModal').modal('show');
    });
  }

  clickOnPopupLink();

});
```

In controller

```
def show
  @work = Work.find(params[:id])
end
```

In show.js.erb

```
$('#myModal').html("<%= j render("/works/modal")%>")
```

Comment: Along the same lines, I made a Gist to show how to do this with bootstrap3-dialog for all "confirm" links. https://gist.github.com/Genkilabs/bdcc5f62c5b46a8e0904

Comment: Make sure you nest single quotes inside double quotes:

`$('#myModal').html("<%= j render('/works/modal')%>")`

Comment: @bachan-smruty any idea why this would show the modal fade out but not the modal dialog? I can see from network/rails console that all assets are being rendered but I jjust get a fade out with no visible form?

Answer (score 5):

You also need to show the modal, add `$('#myModal').modal('show')` in show.js.erb

```
$("#myModal").html("<%= escape_javascript(render 'modal') %>");
$('#myModal').modal('show')
```