# How can I render the show action inside of the Bootstrap 4 Modal?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm having with populating the bootstrap 4 modal with a show action for a clickable image link. I'm currently using Carrierwave for uploading images. At this point, when I click the image, only the modal overlay displays. The modal container with content inside of it, doesn't show at all.

User/Show.html.erb

```
<div class= "container">
<div class="username">@user.username</div>
<div class="posts_container_pos">
        <hr style="border: 2px solid #515558;">
          <%= render 'posts/posts', post_items: @user.posts %>
      </div>
</div>
```

Posts/_Posts.html.erb

```
    <div class"container-fluid">
    <%= @post_items.each do |post| %>
    <%= link_to image_tag(post.photo.url(:medium), style: 'height: 300px; width: 500px;'), modal_post_path(post), data: {:toggle => 'modal', :target => '#reusable_modal'}, lazy: true %>

   <div id="post-modal" class="modal fade"></div>

      <!-- Modal -->
      <div class="modal fade" id="reusable_modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
          <div class="modal-content">

          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
<% end %>

<script type= "text/javascript">
  $(document).on('page:change', function () {
      $(document).on('click', '#reusable_modal [data-dismiss="modal"]',
          function (e) {
            $(e.target).removeData('bs.modal');
            $('#reusable_modal').find('.modal-content').empty();
          });
      $(document).on('click', '[data-target="#reusable_modal"]', function (e) {
        $("#reusable_modal").find(".modal-content").load($(this).attr("href"));
      });
    });
</script>
</div>
```

Posts/Modal.html.erb

```
<div class="modal-header">
  <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
  </button>
  <i><%= image_tag(@post.user.avatar_url(:thumb), class: 'round-image-50') %></i>
  <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel" style="margin-left: 60px; margin-top: -42px;"><%= post.user.username %></h4>
</div>
<div class="modal-body">
  <% if @post.photo.present? %>
  <%= image_tag(@post.photo.url(:large), style: 'max-width: 570px;') %>
  <% end %>
  <div class="modal_post_pos">
    <%= sanitize content_with_emoji(@post.body) %>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="modal-footer">
  <%= render partial: 'comments/template', locals: {commentable: @post, new_comment: @comment} %>
</div>
```

Users_Controller.rb

```
 def show
        if params[:id].to_s.match(/^[0..9]+$/) && !User.friendly.exists?(params[:id])
          render 'public/404.html', status: 404
        else
          @user = User.friendly.find(params[:id])
          @post_items = @user.posts.paginate(page: params[:page])
        end
  end
```

Posts_Controller.rb

```
def modal
    render layout: false
 end

 def show
    @post = Post.find(params[:id])
    @new_comment = Comment.build_from(@post, current_user.id, "")
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html
      format.js
      format.json {render json: @post }
    end
  end
```

Routes.rb

```
resources :posts, except: [:edit, :update] do
    member do
      get 'like', to: 'posts#like'
      get 'dislike', to: 'posts#unlike'
      get :modal
    end
  end
```

Server Log

```
Started GET "/posts/13/modal" for 127.0.0.1 at 2016-04-11 11:41:00 -0400
  ActiveRecord::SchemaMigration Load (0.5ms)  SELECT "schema_migrations".* FROM "schema_migrations"
Processing by PostsController#modal as HTML
  Parameters: {"id"=>"13"}
  User Load (0.5ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = ?  ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT 1  [["id", 5]]
  Rendered posts/modal.html.erb (47.5ms)
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 240ms (ActiveRecord: 1.5ms)

NoMethodError - undefined method `user' for nil:NilClass:
  app/views/posts/modal.html.erb:5:in `_app_views_posts_modal_html_erb__227267806_63456696'
```

Comment: whats your question??

Comment: How can I load the show action inside of bootstrap modal. It's saying nilclass when I click on the link_to show button. When I'm not using the modal, I automatically go to the show.html.erb page. So, it's definitely an issue with the link inside of the modal body itself. <%= render 'posts/post, post: post %> does not work.

Comment: try adding all the `show` code to `modal-body div` itself..see if that works..without separating it out to `partial`

Comment: That seems to work. Could be a messy approach, but at least I know where all of the logic for the code is located if I need to make changes. Thank you.

Comment: Thats indeed "not a Rails" approach and in order to make it happen you probably have to take out complete `modal` block to `_post` partial..please try and see if this approach works.

Comment: Also, why are you using `_posts` partial instead of  `index.html.erb`

Comment: If you look little closely, you will find that you dont have any variable `@post` on `_posts` partial and yet you tried to call it..If thats the case then your code will work you just have to `<% end %>` the loop after `modal` and use `post` variable within `_post` partial to render out all info. at `modal-body` `div`. hope that helps.

Comment: Since, I don't have many objects inside of the modal I will stick to this approach. Thank you.

Comment: After adding the link_to show image directly to the modal. It's only targeting one element on the page. How can I pass the id to the link_to larger image url? <%= image_tag(post.photo.url(:large) %>

Comment: can you please update the question with your latest code..that way I can help you better.

Answer (score 0):

Since you dont have any instance variable `@post` defined on `_posts` partial and still trying to call it within `_posts`, its throwing up error.

The approach to solve this issue if you want to use Bootstrap Modal without extra `js` script is to bring `_post` partial code to `_posts` partial itself and `<% end %>` the loop after modal.

```
<% @post_items.each do |post| %>

<%= link_to image_tag........................

<!-- Modal -->
        <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
          <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
            <div class="modal-content">
              <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                  <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                </button>
                <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Post Show</h4>
              </div>
              <div class="modal-body">
             # complete partial code goes here 
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
<% end %>
```

---

Obviously above approach is not good for performance as it will render everything without the need for it.

Better approach is to use `Ajax` using `jQuery` (my preference). listen for this `button` event (onClick) and load modal on the fly using `ajax` `get` method. consider looking at this approach for better performance reasons.

---

The second solution i am talking about is well explained here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/22144587/2545197

Comment: Can you write out a complete solution?

Comment: I've checked everywhere for a clear cut solution. The most that I was able to find was the form inside of the bootstrap modal.

Comment: @RailzWithLove2035 just added one link to solution please have a look at it. thats the one i was talking about.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this?

In your JS

```
var $modal = $('#ajax-modal');

$.fn.modalmanager.defaults.backdropLimit = 1;

$('.modal-link').on('click', function(){
  var modal_url = $(this).data("modal-url");

  if(modal_url != null){
    // create the backdrop and wait for next modal to be triggered
    $('body').modalmanager('loading');

    $modal.empty().load(modal_url, '', function(){
      $modal.modal();
      // Any callback functions such as let's say selectpicker
      // $('#ajax-modal .selectpicker').selectpicker('refresh');
    });
    return false;
  }
});
```

and in ERB

```
<%= link_to 'Show', post_path(@post), class: 'modal-link', data: { modal_url: post_path(@post) } %>
```

Comment: Can't find 'modalmanager' - What JS file are you using? I'll update this post to include the new approach that I had taken.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem by simply rendering the file for the modal show view instead of the normal show action.

```
  def show
    @post = Post.find(params[:id])
    @new_comment = Comment.build_from(@post, current_user.id, "")
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html {render :file => "posts/modal", layout: false}
      format.js {render :file => "posts/modal", layout: false}
      format.json {render json: @post }
    end
  end
```